# Specify "no header" on a pandas df, after reading the data?

Tags: python, pandas

I know that you can specify no headers when you read data into a pandas dataframe.

But I want to know if it is possible to specify no headers on a pandas dataframe object *after* the data has been read?

something like:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('myfile.csv')
# df assumes first row is header

df.header = None # <-- I want this
```

**Edit: for reasons that are far out of scope of this question, the pandas dataframe reference is all we have. we do not have control over the initialization or the loading of data into the dataframe**

Comment: @piRSquared I think the OP is asking "I've already gone beyond the loading stage, now I want to consider my column headers as the first row without having to reload it again" - So the real question (as far as I read it - hopefully James can tell me if I'm wrong) is not best practice of loading - they already seem to know that... but more like, oh, I've already got this, now how do I correct it...

Comment: fixed... i think

Comment: `df.T.reset_index().T`?

Comment: @JonClements you are somewhat correct. I do indeed want to ignore the loading of the dataframe. lets just assume that is a black box and I have no control over that. what I want to do, is to tell the dataframe object to __not__ assume that the first row is the header, after the dataframe is already loaded.

Answer (score 1):

If you can help it, load it correctly in the first place.

```
pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', header=None, skiprows=1)
```

Otherwise, you want to set the `columns` attribute with a `pd.RangeIndex`

#### In one line

```
pd.read_csv('myfile.csv').pipe(
    lambda d: d.set_axis(pd.RangeIndex(d.shape[1]), axis=1, inplace=False)
)
```

#### With less `lambda`

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
df.columns = pd.RangeIndex(df.shape[1])
```